# PDFBox Newer version extracts data in jumbled order

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to extract data from a particular PDF region using PDFTextStripperByArea and the only data that I am interested to extract is coming in jumbled order, rest all the page data comes properly. This is on PDFBox versions 2.0.7.

When I try the same using legacy version 1.8.x, it extracts the data properly.

The area that I am extracting appears to be different font as compared to the other data in PDF.
I am a little confused on what wrong is happening, is there any way to scrape the data correctly using the newer versions since I cannot fall back on older version due to other dependencies.

What I have tried: -

1. Running the PDF on the latest PDFBox version 2.0.20, still no luck
2. Try debugging out and turns out that setSortByPosition is doing the swapping in the initial step of processing the page, however, I cannot set it false else I lose the new-line characters [ plus the older version works fine when setSortByPosition is set to true]

The code snippet -

```
Rectangle region = new Rectangle();
region.setRect(55, 75.80, 160, 100);
PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFilePath));
PDFTextStripperByArea stripperByArea = new PDFTextStripperByArea ();
stripperByArea.setSortByPosition(true);
stripperByArea.addRegion("CVAM", region);
stripperByArea.extractRegions(pdfDoc.getPages().get(0));
return stripperByArea.getTextForRegion("CVAM");
```

I am sharing the PDF file link in the comment
Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: The fonts in your PDF have very unrealistic metadata. In particular their **Ascent**, **Descent**, **CapHeight**, and **FontBBox** entries contain values that claim that the glyphs are about twice as high as they actually are. As the visual text lines in your PDF are set quite tightly, this means that a PDF tool following those metadata must assume that there actually are not three but one or probably two text lines with some letters raised a bit and some lowered a bit. Sorting, therefore, results in a hodgepodge.

Comment: You say that PDFBox 1.8 extracted the text as desired. There were some changes between versions, and in general these changes *improved* extraction results. Nonetheless, for some files with very weird data, extraction results may have become worse as a consequence.

Comment: 2.0.21 will have the possibility to set own height calculations, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4909

Comment: (As an aside, cropping the page to the address does not remove the rest of the page, it merely hides it. One can trivially remove the crop box and see the whole first page of that *STATEMENT OF ACCOUNT*.)

Comment: Thanks, @mkl Even I was also suspecting the same that the format is not that ideal and reached out for expertise so that somehow I can get some way to get this out using newer version

.Ya, I also realized that cropping doesn't change the data. However since it had some sensitive data, I preferred to do this so that at least it is not visible to folks that are not really picking this up and just visiting :)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, Thanks waiting for version 21

Comment: As of now, I am removing the file since I think the time being there is no way to go forward with existing versions.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr As you pointed out that issue, I looked into it a bit. I think I spotted an issue, see my comment to the issue.

Comment: @mkl thanks, I'll have a look tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fonts in your PDF have very unrealistic metadata. In particular their **Ascent**, **Descent**, **CapHeight**, and **FontBBox** entries contain values that claim that the glyphs are about twice as high as they actually are. As the visual text lines in your PDF are set quite tightly, this means that a PDF tool following those metadata must assume that there actually are not three but one or probably two text lines with some letters raised a bit and some lowered a bit. Sorting, therefore, results in a hodgepodge.

You can check that not only PDFBox has issues with these fonts. E.g. opening the PDF in Adobe Reader and clicking into the text you get a giant cursor bar:

[image: screen shot]

and copying&pasting the address results in

> 1D4A0N0I EHL IDD DEPNO WELALKLES DR MT PLEASANT SC 29464-9473

Nonetheless, following @Tilman's remark that *2.0.21 will have the possibility to set own height calculations,* I made use of that feature in the current PDFBox development head to supply a constant, low font height:

```
PDFTextStripperByArea stripperByArea = new PDFTextStripperByArea() {
    @Override
    protected float computeFontHeight(PDFont font) throws IOException {
        return .5f;
    }
};
stripperByArea.setSortByPosition(false);
stripperByArea.addRegion("CVAM", region);
stripperByArea.extractRegions(pdfDoc.getPages().get(0));
String text = stripperByArea.getTextForRegion("CVAM");
```

*(from [ExtractText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractText.java#L907) test `testCustomFontHeightYOYO`)*

Both with `SortByPosition` set to `true` and `false` the result now is:

> DANIEL D POWELL
> 1400 HIDDEN LAKES DR
> MT PLEASANT SC 29464-9473

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the help, I will try the results on the development head and wait for the release